# Existence of minimizer

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f(x)$ be a continuous function such that $\lim_{\|x\|\to+\infty}f(x)=+\infty$. Prove that the function $f$ has at least one minimizer. It looks obvious, but I don't know how to write it formally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that the domain is finite dimensional.

Pick some point $x_0$ and find some $M$ such that if $\|x\| > M$, then $f(x) > f(x_0)+1$. Then you know that the minimizer must lie in the set $B=\{x | \|x\| \le M \}$, which is compact. Since it is compact and $f$ is continuous, it has a minimum on $B$.